# Pagination problems, non-pagination hyperlinks affected by $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, pagination

I notice that $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] makes all hyper links redirect to my pagination page. I don't mind that because that's how the script is structured but how can I make a separate section of hyper links that is not pagination related and that is not affected by the pagination section.
What I mean by other links is I need to add a home button on that page that is  not affected by $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] so I can go to my home page. Here’s the link to that script.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H9cu18agBIjSrtnH0RVdzByMHDtAPt2efRQUAXzMxBA/edit

Comment: Isn't there any better way to paste code than a google doc? :P

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] will take you to the current page url, while you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/home' to redirecting to home page.

Comment: Can I use$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] or something similar that links to another website just in case if I add other links on that same page that leads to another website?

Comment: well server know itself, for letting server know other url or server you need to define url as constant then you can use that.

eg:

 define('OTHER_WEBSITE','google.com'); //defining constant
use <a href="<?=OTHER_WEBSITE?>">Google</a> //using constant

Comment: I'm using what you suggested me what I should do but I don't think i'm doing it right. For example. $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'. $_SERVER[‘HTTP_HOST’].’/homepage.'?pn='. $next .'">Next</a> '; it keeps giving me errors.

Comment: use this $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/homepage?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';

Comment: O wait that's for the controls sorry for overlooking that. To be honest this is some one else's script. I was in a hurry to get this going, so what other options do I have because I notice If I change all the . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . sections then it will still affect any non-pagination links whats another solution to this?

Comment: i think it will work just don't forget to use http:// before $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] otherwise it will append to the current url.

eg: <a href="http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/homepage?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>

Comment: Thanks man I'm sorry but I think I confused you I notice the buttons shouldn't be touch at all now come and think about it because its part of the power of the pagination. Is there any way where I can add other links to other websites with out the pagination affecting non-pagination -hyperlinks. Because every time I try to put a link outside the pagination section it affects that to so how can I fixed that.

Comment: Here's a link to my problem that i made for the public to understand what i'm going thru right now.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L6TAFGR-hzWgdmDeQLZafPCWDqoeJYYzjIFrTA1jqQg/edit

Comment: I figure it out thanks every one for your help. The problem was that I didn't  add the correct hyperlink structure it was something so tiny wow.